# Problemas com Memcached + Django + Celery(RabbitMQ)

Tags: python, django, rabbitmq, memcached

Estou tendo problemas com o uso do **memcached + celery(django)**. Meu programa faz uma consulta num banco de dados, atraves de um cursor, cria chuncks com o retorno do banco e envia esses chunks para serem processados pelo Celery (uso o RabbitMQ como worker). Eu preciso do resultado desse processamento para dar sequencia, para isso eu estou tentando salva-lo via Memcached.

views.py:

```
class Sound(APIView):

    def get(self, request):

        #Aqui são feitos alguns pré-processamentos necessarios para a sequencia do código.

        query = ('MINHA CONSULTA SQL AQUI')

        cache.clear()
        cursor = connection.cursor()
        cursor_size = cursor.execute(query)
        print(cursor_size)
        idcelery = 0

        while True:
            row = cursor.fetchmany(int(cursor_size/20))
            if not row:
                break;

            control = teste.s(idcelery, variaveis).apply_async()
            idcelery += 1

        while control.ready() == False:
            pass

        resultado = 0

        if cache.get('20'):
            resultado = 20
        elif cache.get('40'):
            resultado = 40
        elif cache.get('80'):
            resultado = 80
        elif cache.get('90'):
            resultado = 90

        print(cache.get('20'))
        print(cache.get('40'))
        print(cache.get('80'))
        print(cache.get('90'))

        print(resultado)

        return HttpResponse(json.dumps(resultado), content_type="application/json; charset=utf-8")
```

tasks.py

```
@shared_task
def teste(idcelery, variaveis):

    for campos in row:
        #Aqui é feito todo o processamento da minha query, no final ela resulta em um valor para a minha registerpercent.

        if registerpercent == 20:
            print(registerpercent)
            cache.set('20', True)

        elif registerpercent == 40:
            cache.set('40', True)

        elif registerpercent == 80:
            cache.set('80', True)

        elif registerpercent == 90:
            cache.set('90', True)
```

No caso, com base no resultado da minha task, um valor é salvo na memória cache, sendo 20, 40, 80 ou 90. Esses valores tem pesos diferentes, sendo a ordem de prioridade: 20>40>80>90 (ou seja, caso o 20 ocorra, o mesmo é quem deve ser retornado pelo programa, idependente dos outros valores que possam ocorrer, e assim sucessivamente até o 90).

O problema é que em alguns testes que fiz, mesmo o worker encontrando o valor de maior peso, ele não chega a ser salvo no cache, retornando assim um valor de menor peso (90). Alguem saberia me dizer o porque disso estar ocorrendo? Percebi também, que nem sempre no terminal do worker, aparece o print do registerpercent com o valor 20, porém o valor é retornado corretamente.